# Making Api call on View DidLoad with MVVM swift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have an application where I want to make an API call once the screen is awaken in the ViewController. Basically, I am using Universal Link to activate the ViewCOntroller and when it displays the UIViewController, I want to make an API call based on the Data got. I am currently using the MVVM Architecture and I have added my code below

**My ViewModel**

```
    class EmailVerificationViewModel: ViewModel, ViewModelType {

        struct Input {
            let editEmailTrigger: Driver<Void>
        }

        struct Output {

        }

        let routeManager: BehaviorRelay<RouteMatchResult?>
        let currentEmail: BehaviorRelay<String?>

        init(routeManager: RouteMatchResult?, provider: Api, currentEmail: String?) {
            self.routeManager = BehaviorRelay(value: routeManager)
            self.currentEmail = BehaviorRelay(value: currentEmail)
            super.init(provider: provider)
        }

        func transform(input: Input) -> Output {

         // THE CALL I WANT TO MAKE
            routeManager.errorOnNil().asObservable()

            .flatMapLatest { (code) -> Observable<RxSwift.Event<User>> in
            log("=========++++++++++++==========")
//            guard let code = code else {return}
            let params = code.values
                let challengeId = Int(params["xxx"] as? String ?? "0")
                let login = LoginResponseModel(identifier: params["xxxx"] as? String, key: params["xxxxxx"] as? String, oth: params["xxxxx"] as? String, id: 0, challengeId: challengeId)

            return self.provider.postVerifyApp(challengeId: login.challengeId!, oth: login.oth!, identifier: login.identifier!)
            .trackActivity(self.loading)
            .trackError(self.error)
            .materialize()
        }.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (event) in
            switch event {
            case .next(let token):
                log(token)
                AuthManager.setToken(token: token)
//                self?.tokenSaved.onNext(())
            case .error(let error):
                log(error.localizedDescription)
            default: break
            }
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

            return Output()
        }
    }
```

**My Viewcontroller**

```
override func bindViewModel() {
        super.bindViewModel()
        guard let viewModel = viewModel as? EmailVerificationViewModel else { return }

        let input = EmailVerificationViewModel.Input(editEmailTrigger: editEmailBtn.rx.tap.asDriver())
        let output = viewModel.transform(input: input)

        viewModel.loading.asObservable().bind(to: isLoading).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
        viewModel.parsedError.asObservable().bind(to: error).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

        isLoading.asDriver().drive(onNext: { [weak self] (isLoading) in
            isLoading ? self?.startAnimating() : self?.stopAnimating()
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)


        error.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (error) in
            var title = ""
            var description = ""
            let image = R.image.icon_toast_warning()
            switch error {
            case .serverError(let response):
                title = response.message ?? ""
            }
            self?.view.makeToast(description, title: title, image: image)
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
    }
```

so how can I make the call on the commented like `THE CALL I WANT TO MAKE` once the application catches the universal link and loads up. Basically making an API call on viewDidLoad

Comment: Can you edit the question to include what is the issue you are encountering and what have you tried so far and what didn't worked? That would be great, as for as I see your question there are multiple interpretation to what would you like to achieve...

Comment: Okay @denis_lor done the edit check it now

Answer (score 0):

The code in your sample was way more than is needed to answer the question. Here is how you make a network call on viewDidLoad:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var viewModel: ViewModel!

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let input = ViewModel.Input()
        let output = viewModel.transform(input: input)
        output.viewData
            .bind(onNext: { viewData in
                // setup the view with viewData
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

class ViewModel {
    struct Input { }
    struct Output {
        let viewData: Observable<ViewData>
    }

    init(api: API) {
        self.api = api
    }

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        let viewData = api.networkCall()
            .map { ViewData(from: $0) }
        return Output(viewData: viewData)
    }

    let api: API
}
```